# catch multiple exceptions at once in java?

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.io.*;

class West1 extends Exception {
    private String msg;
    public West1() {
    }

    public West1(String msg) {
        super(msg);
        this.msg=msg;
    }

    public West1(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public West1(String msg,Throwable cause) {
        super(msg,cause);
        this.msg=msg;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return msg;
    }


    public String getMessage() {
        return msg;
    }
}

public class West {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new West1("Custom Exception.....");
        }catch(West1 ce) {
            System.out.println(ce.getMessage());
            //throw new NumberFormatException();
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fne) {
            fne.printStackTrace();  
        }/*catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }
}
```

In the above code, `NumberFormatException` is thrown from catch block it compile and run successfully but when `FileNotFoundException` is thrown from catch block it will not compile. Following Errors are thrown:

```
West.java:40: error: exception FileNotFoundException is never thrown in body of
corresponding try statement
                }catch(FileNotFoundException fne){
West.java:39: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught
or declared to be thrown
                        throw new FileNotFoundException();
```

So my question is what is reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: Take a look at checked vs unchecked explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Comment: What the message says.  You must add FileNotFoundException to the `throws` clause of the method, if you're letting it "escape".

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormatException is a RuntimeException, meaning that it's not required to be declared in all methods it may be thrown. This means that, unlike FileNotFoundException, the compiler can not know if it can get thrown in a block or not.

Answer (score 0):

The title implies you are trying to `catch` multiple exceptions at once, and your code implies you understand that you can have multiple `catch` blocks for a single `try` block to `catch` different types of exceptions. Everything is good so far, but you seem to misunderstand exactly where the `try`-`catch` catches errors.

Here is you code. I removed the comments to make it more concise.

```
public class West {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new West1("Custom Exception.....");
        } catch(West1 ce) {
            System.out.println(ce.getMessage());
            throw new FileNotFoundException(); // <-- Must be caught
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fne) { // <-- Never thrown
            fne.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
}
```

The first compiler error is because the `catch` block that is for catching `FileNotFoundException`'s `try` block never throws `FileNotFoundException`. The second compiler error is because `FileNotFoundException` is a [checked exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129). Because it is a checked exception your code must either

- handle it (by catching it with `try`-`catch`)
- let everyone know it could throw it (`public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException { ...`).

From the context of your code, you seem to be going with the first option, handling it with `try`-`catch`, but you have the `catch` in the wrong place.

`catch` blocks don't catch exceptions, `try` blocks do. `catch` blocks specify what to do with the actual caught exception.

```
public class West {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new West1("Custom Exception.....");
        } catch(West1 ce) {
            System.out.println(ce.getMessage());
            try {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException fne) {
                fne.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try that instead. Notice how you can have a `try` instead of a `catch`. This wouldn't matter if `FileNotFoundException` wasn't a [checked exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129).

Comment: Please provide explanation as to why you downvote when you do. I feel my answer answers OP's question well, but will still edit to be more clear.